# Notice vs. pay attention

Tags: verbs, diction

I want to ask you, the English native speakers, regarding to a post in my blog which was
commented by a visitor:

> Before applying for a job, please notice the following requirements:
>   write down your application letter neatly, attach your latest CV, ….
>   the copy of your IDCard and your latest close-up photo, and send to us
>   using well-sealed envelope.
>
> a. to enclose
>
> b. enclose
>
> c. encloses
>
> d. enclosed
>
> e. enclosing

Here is the comment of a visitor:

> I have seen examples of national exams where the English was so wrong
>   that there were no correct options. Even the example included here is
>   a bit strange. We would never use ‘notice’ we would say ‘pay attention
>   to’. And write down is not appropriate in this context, it should be
>   write.

Could you explain me about that "wrong example"? I found that
example somewhere on net and I do forgotten the source. Is it possible
for you to mark and correct the example (plus the options)? Why
'notice' and 'pay attention' are different, and why 'write down'
couldn't fit the context?

Thank you,
Khadis

Comment: Please edit the question to quote the relevant part of your blog post and the comment. Questions need to be self-contained and helpful to the internet in general.

Comment: 'Notice' and 'pay attention' **are** different, see a dictionary.

Comment: I have read EN-ID dictionary and they have "almost" the same meaning. I am still so hesitate, so could you please give me examples so that I can draw a conclusion?
And for the options, why they are also "wrong"? What words should fit the options? Thank you.

Comment: I'd probably write 'please *satisfy* the following requirements'.

Answer (score 1):

"Notice" suggests "becoming aware of".  You can ignore something after you've noticed it.  "Pay attention to" in this context instead means maintaining attention beyond first noticing the instructions — that is, they want you to keep the requirements in mind and follow the instructions.

At least in the US, it would be idiomatic to say "please note the following requirements", which implies reading them and also following them.

"Write" is what you do to the written product.  You write a book, or a note, or a letter.  "Write down" is what you do to material which exists in your mind but is not currently written.  "Write down this phone number", "I have this great idea for a book": "Well, write it down!"  And one more: "write down a recipe" means to record a recipe that you already know, but "write a recipe" implies creating the recipe as you write it.

The options are fine.  The answer is (b) since it's a command, just like the other parts of the list: "write", "attach", "enclose", "send".  But there's more to fix:

> Before applying for a job, please note the following requirements: write your
>   application letter neatly, attach your latest CV, [...] a copy of your ID card
>   and a recent close-up photo, and send them to us in a well-sealed envelope.

Comment: @wordsmythe Thanks for the improvements on "pay attention to"

Comment: Thank you, for the explanation, @wordsmythe. So helpful :)